# View On Web paradox in Android App

Tags: discussion, android-app

I was browsing a question on the Android App. Clicked on the options, then selected [View on Web]. However, I have set my global setting to always open up stack-urls using the Android App. So it tried to open up the url in chrome, but was auto-directed right back to the page in the Android app.

I realize that this is due to my associating stack-links with the app. So is there any way to either:

1. Detect that I have set this and not offer [View on Web] as an option for user's that would be redirected back to the app?
2. Override the redirect for a request originating within the app, and force it to open in the browser?